# PHP で子クラスに独自の実装をすると警告が出る Warning: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php

現在子クラスに独自の実装をしていくという学習をしています。
親クラス Post を継承する子クラス showSponsor を作成してみました。
子クラスのコンストラクタの引数に親クラスのプロパティ'$text'、と子クラスで
新たに作成した'$sponsor'を入れました。

その後、newで新しく作った'showSponsor 'のインスタンスを作りました。
スポンサー名は'Yahoo'としてみました。
$posts[2] = new SponsoredPost('hello hello', ’Yahoo');

その後、同様に新しく作成した ’showSponsor()’ メソッドを表示するために
$posts[2]->showSponsor();
を追加しました。

この記述で実行すると

"Warning: Use of undefined constant ’Yahoo’ - assumed '’Yahoo’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs…"

と出ます。「'Yahoo'という定義されていない定数を使っている」というような意味かと思います。

子クラスである'SponsoredPost'内の sponsoreのどこかにミスがあるのでしょうか？
エラー行はコード内に記述したある
$posts[2] = new SponsoredPost('hello hello', ’Yahoo');
の部分です。

表示結果では一応’Yahoo’の文字出ていますが、 ' (シングルクォート) も一緒についています。文字列ということを表すためにつけたものです。

初学者の自分にはエラーの原因がわかりません。
もしエラーの原因がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
宜しくお願い致します。

---

```
<?php

class Post
{
private $text;

public function __construct($text)
{
$this->text = $text;
}

public function show()
{
printf('%s',$this->text);
}
}

class SponsoredPost extends Post
{
private $sponsor;

public function __construct($text, $sponsor)
{
parent:: __construct($text);
$this->sponsor = $sponsor;
}

public function showSponsor()
{
printf('%s', $this->sponsor);
}

}

$posts=[];
$posts[0] = new Post('hello');
$posts[1] = new Post('hello again');

//★エラー行
$posts[2] = new SponsoredPost('hello hello', ’Yahoo');

$posts[0]->show();
echo "<br>";
$posts[1]->show();
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$posts[2]->show();
echo "<br>";
$posts[2]->showSponsor();
```

---

Comment: 質問に貼られたコードでエラーが出ている箇所の `’Yahoo'` は先頭のシングルクォートが全角文字のようですが、実際に実行したコードも同じでしょうか？

Comment: VSCodeを使っているのですが分かりませんでした。仰る通り全角のクオーテーションがエラーの原因でした。Yahooの文字色が正しく記述されると黄色のところが赤色になっていました。今後十分注意して記述します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄でのやり取りで解決したようなので改めて。

---

エラーが出ている箇所の `’Yahoo'` は先頭のシングルクォートが全角文字になっており、これが原因ではないでしょうか？